# Flutter | Text on top of bottom navigation bar screens

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have `bottom navigation` menu items where I successfully change through pages. I want to
add a text widget to the top of the screens. as shown in below code

```
body: _kTabPages[_currentTabIndex],
bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavBar,
```

and then i changed it to this,

```
body: 
      Column(
        children: [
          Text('Hello Text'),
          _kTabPages[_currentTabIndex],
        ],
      ),
     
      bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavBar,
```

but now the pages are disappearing and i am only left with the text at the top, the navigation items at the bottom, and a blank white screen in the middle where the pages are supposed to go. With the error :

```
bottom overflowed by infinity pixels
```

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56354923/flutter-bottom-overflowed-by-infinity-pixels) i managed to find out the solution which is to wrap the screens by Expanded so my answer is now

```
body:
      Column(
        children: [
          Text('Hello Text'),
          Expanded(child: _kTabPages[_currentTabIndex]),
        ],
      ),

      bottomNavigationBar: bottomNavBar,
```